# Changing a Fieldset's Background Color with Nested Input Fields using CSS

Tags: css, input, background, focus, fieldset

I'm using this solution:
[Is it possible to change a fieldset's background-color on input:focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662874/is-it-possible-to-change-a-fieldsets-background-color-on-inputfocus/29454224#29454224)

... to change the background of a fieldset as a user moves through a form. On a basic level this works great. On a more advanced level, I'm having trouble making this work on input fields that are nested inside of a conditional div. In other words, the inputs are no longer siblings to the div in his example.

To give you a visual, this works:

```
<fieldset>
<input>
<div></div>
</fieldset>
```

But this does not:

```
<fieldset> 
<div class="conditional"> 
<input> 
</div> 
<div></div> 
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you **can** now affect the parent of an input on focus with

```
:focus-within
```

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has received focus or contains an element that has received focus. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the :focus pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by :focus. (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
fieldset:focus-within {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input>
</fieldset>
```